# How can I show a many-to-many field values in a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i wrote a code about music and used *Many-To-Many-Field()* as genre but when i try to show genres it just shows : `Genre['a number']`

template:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}
    
{% block content %}
    
    <form>
        {% if mdata.image %}
            <img src="mdata.image.url" height="500" width="500">
        {% endif %}
    
        {% for field in form %}
            <p>{{ field.label }} : {{ field.value}}</p>
            }
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
    
    <a href="{% url 'pages:edit_music' mdata.id %}">edit</a>

{% endblock %}
```

models is here:(i didnt know which one u need so pasted both of them)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()



class Mdata(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    released_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=0)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audios/',null=True,blank=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()+" by "+self.artist.title()
```

forms.py:(its just a simple form im using)

```
[![class MdataForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Mdata
    fields =\[
        'name',
        'artist',
        'album',
        'genre',
        'nation',
        'duration',
        'released_in',
        'image',
        'audio',
        ]
```

and here the render :dunno if this is enough
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5eK2.png

Comment: Share your `Genre` model.

Comment: can you share the form that you are using, and perhaps a screenshot of the rendered form?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added can you check pls?

Answer (score 0):

This could be that you don't have a `__str__` method on your Genre model. Add a `__str__` method and return the genre name. That would be something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

`self.name` here being the field on your genre model used to specify the name. In the sample image below, I set the custom user to return the username by default, that way anywhere I call a user it will automatically show the name of the genre.

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid4)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True, null=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(_("password"), max_length=128, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Even if you customize str method, it is only called when you render the field as a select multiple tag, within which option tags have the inner html of genre.name.title().

Comment: In your forms.py, customize MdataForm’s Genre field as genre = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Genre, to_field_name='name'). However, this way genre’s name cannot be further modified by .title() method